# Radio buttons misaligned in IE7 and IE9

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer, radio-button

I have implemented two radio buttons within a table and they appear correctly in all versions of Chrome and Firefox but show incorrectly in IE7 and IE9, see below. The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/1154514). Thanks in advance!

[image: radio buttons misaligned]

Comment: `<SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 120%"><LABEL for=product_complete>myHalo Complete</LABEL><B>` that looks like HTML from the 90ies… You maybe just embed the input into the label and use CSS for styling.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because of the span besides the radio button and you have a bold text in the span. Try to set some negative `margin-top` to radio buttons it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing both the <span> and the <b> and it still behaves the same way. Any more ideas?

Comment: Did you set margin-top to radio button?

Answer (score 1):

- use blueprintcss.org [compatible with browsers/OS](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/wiki/Browser-compatibility-list), 960.gs or similar CSS library
  users have already made it work with multiple browsers/platforms
- Very "raw" solution if nothing else works. Make tables for alignment.
  This is not a recommended approach though for standards compliance.

```
+-----------------------------+------------+
| +----+------------------+   |            |
| | o  | My halo complete |   | image here |
| +----+------------------+   |            |
+-----------------------------+------------+
```

- define CSS "td.middle { vertical-align: middle;}"
  then apply using tables

  <td class="middle">
- use [custom rendering](http://www.andreapinchi.it/how-to-style-radio-buttons-with-pure-css/), if required